# CastingDevicePicker doesn't find the emulator

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to stream video to the remote device in UWP C#. I use a MediaElement and CastDevicePicker. I did everything following the article - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/media-casting. CastDevicePciker doesn't find the emulator (screenshot - https://ibb.co/5sgLyq3). Ping to the device with the application is successful, and ping to the emulator is successful as well. So, I think that the Device with the application and the emulator is on the same local network.

What I am doing wrong?

I try to get a connection with the emulator, but nothing happened
I use a Microsoft Emulator - https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/microsoft-emulator/9N0TN65P5BF6?hl=en-us&gl=us

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior. Based on the document- [CastingDevice object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.casting.castingdevice?view=winrt-22621) represents **a physical device** that is capable of supporting casting connections and rendering media content sent to it.  When you are trying to use [CastingDevicePicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.Casting.CastingDevicePicker?view=winrt-22621) to pick an emulator, it is not considered as a [CastingDevice object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.casting.castingdevice?view=winrt-22621). So the emulator is not listed. Please try to use **a physical device** to test.